# В idea не показывает папку

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

В настройках проекта указал не показывать папку `node_modules`.
 Теперь во всех проектах я не вижу эту папку. Помогите найти настройку.
Сейчас настройки такие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть node_modules не исключён. Я его все равно не вижу. Как поправить?

Comment: попробуйте режим отображения структуры проекта поменять

Comment: что это и как сделать?

Comment: слева, в дереве отображения файлов проекта есть изображение шестерёнки и рядом треугольничек - там и есть возможность переключать режим отображения структуры и содержимого проекта

Answer (score 3):

В моем случае помогло удалить папку из списка `Ignore files and folders`:

[image: Settings->File Types->Ignore files and folders]

*P.S. После будьте готовы к оочень долгой индексации..*